# Update campaign member status

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I would like to modify the statuses of campaign members in the CRM Salesforce based on their activity in Journey Builder.
Specifically, if a customer opens an email, I want the corresponding campaign member in Salesforce to have an "open" status.
To achieve this, I created a campaign in the CRM and added myself as a campaign member for testing purposes. Additionally, I created a journey in Marketing Cloud with a campaign member activity and used the CRM campaign as the audience for the journey.
Despite these efforts, the statuses are not updating even when the email is opened.

Can you provide assistance with this issue please?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you configured the journey and the activity, as it’s written now it’s not possible for us to help you

Comment: Also, did you use an engagement split in your journey?

Answer (score 0):

The order should be as follows (I'm assuming you use MC Connect):

- After an email is sent (using either Email Sends (or Bulk Send using Distributed Marketing)), Salesforce first creates an Email Send record.
- Upon a reaction from the recipient, an Individual Email Result record is created
- Lastly the Campaign Member Status should be updated (*)

(*) Mind that this will only happen when the Campaign member statuses are correctly mapped with the subscriber statuses in Marketing Cloud. You should be able to set this up using this link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_co_configure_campaign_member_tracking.htm&type=5